# EF not showing database in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server Management Studio 2019. I have created a database

[image]

Now, by using the database-first approach, I am trying to add the model but It's not showing the database.

[image]

I have also tried to change the data source to `other` but still, it's not showing my database

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the server name with SQLExpress too

i.e. Desktop-HFI8QQ8\SQLexpress